# Flutter Run : FAILURE Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

Please help me. Since I cloned this project from git I always get the following error message

```
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/encoder/tex/functions/frac.dart:113:37: Error: The getter 'optionsDiff' isn't defined for the class 'GreenNode'.
 - 'GreenNode' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'optionsDiff'.
      final remainingOptions = node.optionsDiff.removeStyle();
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/encoder/tex/functions/frac.dart:138:37: Error: The getter 'optionsDiff' isn't defined for the class 'GreenNode'.
 - 'GreenNode' is from 'package:flutter_math_fork/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/ast/syntax_tree.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'optionsDiff'.
      final remainingOptions = node.optionsDiff.removeStyle();
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\SRC\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\SRC\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              9.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried

```
flutter pub get
flutter clean
```

But still, get the error message above. I am getting error messages only in this project. if I do `flutter run` in another project it can run without problem.

Comment: This means that you're propably using older version of that package, is this repo you cloned old ?